# subring of $\mathbb{Q}_p$

Tags: ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\Bbb Q_p$ be a p-adic field.
I know $\Bbb Q$ has infinitely many number of subrings since they are multiplicatively set of $\Bbb Z$ which are generated by primes.

Since $\Bbb Q$ is a subring of $\Bbb Q_p$, I understand $\Bbb Q_p$ has infinitely many number of subrings.
But I cannot concretely describe all of them.
Are there any known results?

Thank you for helping me.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it even has infinitely many *subfields*.

Comment: Although there are infinitely many subrings, most of them are not "concretely describable", and are not quite interesing in theory. Usually people are satisfied with understanding the interesting ones, such as $\Bbb Q$, $\Bbb Z$, $\Bbb Z_p$.

Comment: Are there well-known results about Zp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My advice is: *Forget about it – no real chance of classifying all the subrings*.

Remember that $\Bbb{Q}_p$ is in a sense analogous to $\Bbb{R}$, and you don't really want to try to classify all the subrings of $\Bbb{R}$ either.

As Torsten Schoeneberg pointed out, $\Bbb{Q}_p$ has infinitely many distinct subfields. An easy way of seeing that is to observe that, due to Hensel lifting, $\Bbb{Q}_p$ contains the square roots of all the integers $n$ such that $n$ is a quadratic residue modulo $p$. That's infinitely many distinct quadratic subfields already let alone other algebraic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$. I'm fairly sure that the transcendence degree of $\Bbb{Q}_p/\Bbb{Q}$ is also infinite (possibly continuum cardinality?). This really kills all hope.

Answer (score 1):

Let $R\hookrightarrow \mathbb Q_p$ be an inclusion. We obviously have that $R$ is an integral domain, and hence induces a field extension $\mathbb Q_p/\text{Frac} R,$ where $\text{Frac} R$ denotes the quotient field of $R.$

Conversely, given a subfield $K\subseteq \mathbb Q_p,$ all integral domains $R$ with $\text{Frac} R=K$ induces an inclusion $R\subseteq \mathbb Q_p.$