# Subrings of $\Bbb Z_p$

Tags: ring-theory, p-adic-number-theory

Let $\Bbb Z_p$ be the ring of p-adic integers.
Then, I can list some subrings of $\Bbb Z_p$, like $\Bbb Z$, and... localization of $\Bbb Z$ at $(p^n)$ for some nonnegative integer $n$.

So I can say the number of subrings of $\Bbb Z_p$ is infinite, but I cannot concretely describe all of them.
Are there any known results?

I would be appreciated if you help me describing all of subrings of $\Bbb Z_p$. Thank you.

Comment: You could and maybe should have mentioned that you asked a strongly related question shortly before: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3587674/96384. Note that the answers to both questions rely on the very same principles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are infinitely many subrings of $\mathbb Z_p$ of the form $\mathbb Z[\alpha]$ for $\alpha$ algebraic over $\mathbb Q$, of any degrees you like, via Hensel's lemma. For example, for $p=1\mod 4$, there is $\alpha\in\mathbb Z_p$ such that $\alpha^2=-1$. Generally, for an algebraic extension $\mathbb Q(\alpha)$ (with $\alpha$ integral over $\mathbb Z$) in which $p$ splits completely, $\mathbb Z_p$ contains a copy of the algebraic integers of the extension.

Also, on cardinality considerations, there are uncountably many $\alpha\in\mathbb Z_p$ that are transcendental over $\mathbb Q$.

I doubt that all subrings are classifiable...